# Comparing two DNA sequences to annotate differences

Tags: python, alignment

I'm trying to take two sequences of DNA and trying to compare them to determine differences, if any, in particular deletions or insertions.

I get an error that the list index is out of range.

> Errors:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/DiegoJaime/Desktop/MuSK_Fc Alignment_copy.py", line 59, in 
>       GeneSort( 'FL_MuSK.txt', 'FL_MuSK_Fc.txt')
>     File "/Users/DiegoJaime/Desktop/MuSK_Fc Alignment_copy.py", line 49, in GeneSort
>       print( 'Site of deletion\nStart: %s : End: %s' %(string1[0],string2[-1]))
>   IndexError: list index out of range

```
                def GeneSort(inFileName1, inFileName2):
                in1= inFileName1
                masterlist1 = open(in1, 'r')
                in2 = inFileName2
                masterlist2 = open(in2, 'r')

            # Output file of gene names for GO searches
                Overlap= 'OverlapGenes.txt'
                GeneListOutput= open(Overlap, 'w')

                nt1= ''
                nt2=''
                for line1 in masterlist1:
                    line1= line1.strip()
                    nt1+= line1


                for line2 in masterlist2:
                    line2=line2.strip()
                    nt2+=line2

                i = 0
                string1 = []
                while i < len(nt2)-1:
                    if nt1[i] != nt2[i]:
                        string1.append(i)


                    i += 1

                print('%d  :  %d' %(len(nt1), len(nt2)))


                j= len(nt2)-1
                i= len(nt1)-1
                string2 = []
                count=0
                while count < len(nt2)-1:

                    if nt1[i] == nt2[j]:

                        string2.append(i)

                        j = j-1
                        i = i-1
                    count +=1


                print( 'Site of deletion\nStart: %s : End: %s' %(string1[0],string2[-1]))



            GeneSort( 'FL_MuSK.txt', 'FL_MuSK_Fc.txt')
```

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is. Show us the entire error message, including the line that causes the error.

Comment: Edit your post to include the traceback -- it's hard to read stuffed into a comment.

Comment: Errors included in post

Comment: `string1` and/or `string2` are empty lists, and therefore you cannot access elements inside them with `string1[0]` and `string2[-1]`.

Comment: As a simple debugging step, try printing `string1` and `string2` just before the error line.